# android find nested view having focus

Tags: android, focus

How can I find the leaf view, in a large hierarchy of views, which has focus?

I've tried

```
ViewGroup.getFocusedChild()
```

which returns null, when called from a group high in the hierarchy.

I also tried

```
Activity.getCurrentFocus()
```

which seems to return the highest focusable view, not the leaf view.

The use case is to restore keyboard focus to the view after temporarily removing it from the view hierarchy and later restoring it. Note, that I'm not directly removing the view, but removing a ViewGroup at some higher level.

Answer (score 1):

I try  with recursion

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewGroup removedViewGroup;
    ViewGroup upperViewGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void removeBtn(View v) {
        removeViewGroupHavingFocused((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
    }

    public void addBtn(View v) {

        upperViewGroup.addView(removedViewGroup);
    }

    public void removeViewGroupHavingFocused(ViewGroup vg) {

        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View child = vg.getChildAt(i);

            if (child.isFocused()) {  // View or its descendants is focused
                if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    removeViewGroupHavingFocused((ViewGroup) child);
                } else { // view

                    upperViewGroup = (ViewGroup) child.getParent().getParent();
                    removedViewGroup = (ViewGroup) child.getParent();
                    upperViewGroup.removeView(removedViewGroup);
                }

                return;
            } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                removeViewGroupHavingFocused((ViewGroup) child);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I'm getting "false" when testing whether a ViewGroup contains a focused view.

Comment: `findViewHavingFocused((ViewGroup) child);` this line use `child` not `vg`, and yes I can run it but don't know if it is what you want

Comment: Yes, I saw the error of child versus vg. No problem. But I find that the recursion does not work. In otherwords, isFocused() seems to return true only if the view itself has focus, not if a descendant of the view has focus. However, there is another function, hasFocus(), which may be the solution.

Comment: Check out my edited answer, recursion can eventually find the focused view then you can manipulate it

Comment: hasFocus() works. isFocused() only applies to a specific view.

Comment: `isFocused()` is the only to get the most inner focused view, using `hasFocused()` may still return some nested `ViewGroup` that you may not want to remove. My edited answer use `getParent()` to achieve your goal

Comment: No. You have to use hasFocus(). I tried both. In fact, I retried Activity.getCurrentFocus() and now it is working for me. I must have done something wrong earlier in my testing.

Comment: Oh, I will try `hasFocus()` later, but gald that you find the problem:)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'll give you a +1